# flex 4, as3: can not import flashx.textLayout; what's wrong?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

in file main.mxml (project AS3/Flex4) can not use class `TextConverter`. When trying to connect:

```
import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;
```

IntelliSense after `flashx.` did not see anything ... what is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your project to use Flash Player 10 and Flex 4 SDK in order to use this class.

Comment: fonini, thanks. I have Flash Player 10. Flex 4 SDK downloaded. SDK as it must be connected to or expanded in some directory?

Comment: You need to extract the downloaded SDK inside the sdks dir, on Flash Builder install dir. Also, you must edit the properties of your project and choose Flash Player 10 and change the default SDK to 4

Comment: in setting project i have plugins:External Player Path: C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\runtimes\player\10.2\win\FlashPlayerDebugger.exe . it's correct. also in directories C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk - 561 M bytes. in downloaded flex_sdk_4.0.0.14159 only 249 M bytes. should I copy a downloaded SDK to the original (new flashdevelop i install month ago).

Comment: wondering what folder textLayout I already have - C: \ Program Files \ FlashDevelop \ Tools \ flexsdk \ frameworks \ projects \ textLayot

Comment: in general, I copied the downloaded SDK to C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk and still nothing... My FlashDevelop version 4.0.0 RC1. The latest version FlashDevelop 4.0.0 RC2. I do not think that things in the. Any idea??

Comment: solution is: press in menu Tools:Global ClassPath:Add ClassPath and set C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\frameworks\projects\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\ . and now flashx available.  :))